# Is this the right way to require ruby gems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, bundler

Hi so i stumbled upon a new way to require my ruby gems in my sinatra app using bundler and i was wondering if this is how i should do it:

My gem file looks like:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'thin'
gem 'haml'
```

My config.ru file looks like:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'

Bundler.require

require './web'
run Sinatra::Application
```

My web.rb file looks like:

```
class MyApp
  before do
    cache_control :public, :max_age => 60
  end

  not_found do
    haml :not_found
  end

  get '/' do
    haml :index
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of these lines from your config.ru file:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'

Bundler.require
```

Just make sure you run

```
bundle install
```

from the terminal to install your gems before starting the application.

Comment: Hi thank you for your suggestion, this app is running on heroku and i run bundle install on my mac before i push it to the git repository because heroku requires a Gemfile.lock.

Comment: You should run bundle install everytime you add a gem and restart locally.

Comment: Yes thats what i do but when it runs on a server i wont be able to run bundle install so thats why im asking about the code above

Comment: When Heroku deploys it automatically runs bundle install.  Running bundle install locally generates a Gemfile.lock file which, yes, you must add to your git repository.

Comment: Ok so now i removed those lines and i get

./web.rb:2: undefined method `before' for MyApp:Class (NoMethodError)
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'

Comment: You need require 'sinatra' at the top of your web.rb file

Comment: Also, MyApp needs to subclass Sinatra::Base

Comment: Ok thanks i added that, so now the other gems that i had in my gem file do i need to require those too, im just going by the bundler docs
http://gembundler.com/v1.2/sinatra.html

Comment: No, you just need to run bundle install from your command line.  It should run then.